# How to use Java execute shell script with argument having PIPE

Tags: java, shell, process

I am trying to execute shell script from java code which execute passed argument as command .
Error if we pass argument with PIPE

Java code section :

```
 List cmd = new ArrayList();
cmd.add("./command.sh");
cmd.add("zcat anil.tar.Z | tar x");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = pb.start();
```

Shell Script:

```
echo $1
$1
```

output stream prints:

zcat anil.tar.Z | tar x
123.tx0000664000175000017500000000000012473403111011236 0ustar  rajeevrajeev

Error Stream prints:

gzip: |.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: tar.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: x.gz: No such file or directory

is there any special way to pass PIPE in the argument list

Comment: You probably have to run the shell explicitly in order to run a pipeline from Java.  Give `"sh -c \"cmd1 | cmd2\""` a try.

Comment: I tried this as                                                                                         cmd.add("sh -c \"zcat 3.tar.Z | tar xf -\"");
ProcessBuilderWrapper pbd = new ProcessBuilderWrapper(cmd);  Error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh -c "zcat 3.tar.Z | tar xf -"": error=2, No such file or directory